# Use autoprefixer with strings or streams

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gulp, autoprefixer

I use babel plugin to transform sass imports into string with Angular2 in order to inline styles right into component code during gulp build. I need to also use autoprefixer, but I wasn't able to make solutions I found working, basically, here is the part of code that renders sass to css:

```
var css = sass.renderSync({
   'data': scss,
   'outputStyle': 'compressed',
   'includePaths': [dir]
}).css.toString();
```

I tried to find autoprefixer plugin working with strings and tried transforming result of `renderSync` to stream and using plugins for streams, but no luck. I don't want to use a workaround writing css to temp file and autoprefixing from there, so maybe there is some solution that I could miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`autoprefixer`](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) is a [`postcss`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss) plugin. That means you have to use it with `postcss`.

The `postcss` [JavaScript API](https://github.com/postcss/postcss#js-api) works by creating a processor that uses the specified plugins. You then pass the CSS string to `.process()`. This returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that gives you access to the result CSS.

```
var postcss = require('postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var css = 'display: flex';

postcss([autoprefixer({ browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions'] })])      
  .process(css)
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.css);
  })
```

Output:

```
display: -webkit-box;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex
```